# Does HTML5 "download" attribute require any server side configuration?

Tags: html

Hell friends,

I am running a very basic example of HTML5 download attribute to download a mp3 file.
That example is working on Chrome but not working on FF (24).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>HTML5 download Attribute Example</title>
<meta name="description" value="" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="SOME_VALID_PATH/Intro.mp3" download="Intro.mp3">Download file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in FF it is playing that mp3 rather then downloading it.
**How ever other examples of download is working on that FF from other demo sites like http://davidwalsh.name/demo/html5-download.php is working.**

Comment: If you think the server in your example page responds differently than yours – then go check it yourself, f.e. using the “net” panel in firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox has a default setting to play mp3 files.

You can enter **about:config** in FF:s address bar to access this setting.
The setting itself is named "**media.windows-media-foundation.enabled**"

So in the end it's a user configuration option whether to download or play - even if FireFox makes a default decision for you. I think, in FireFox, you can "long click" to download the file instead of playing it.

Looking at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#downloading-resources) I think the download attribute should override the FireFox option, so if this still happends I think FireFox is not behaving the way it should.

Comment: No, and we should not really have to. FireFox will never let a web page access its settings that way, and it should not - for the user's sake. The settings are there for the user and browser, not to be fiddled with by the web pages. However - if a user is using FF as their main browser they may know how FireFox behaves downloading mp3-files. That said - I do think the download attribute should override the browser's default behaviour if you look at what the speification says (even though it's a draft).

Comment: Linux (and maybe other...): Set `media.play-stand-alone` to `false`